# How do I save (make the spinner remember) the position of a selected item on the spinner drop down

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

I need to save the selected items  in the spinner. Currently I have 3 sections, topnews/mynews and breakingviews. Each section has a dynamic list consisting of items say topnews has europe/asia/germany/frontnews etc. On the side I have a menu button from where I can add or remove the items to be displayed in each of these 3 categories. Now,everytime I select an item in the spinner say "germany" and then I click on the menu button and add or remove any item above or below germany, the position shifts on the spinner too , to the previously selected item or to the next item. How do I make the spinner remember the last selection irrespective of the item added or removed from the menu list through the menu button.

I have added the following code in the sharedpreferencesmanager.java:

```
private static final String PROPERTY_NEWS_INDEX = "newsindex";
public void savenewsselectedindex(int selectedindex) {
        mSharedPreferences.edit().putInt(PROPERTY_NEWS_INDEX, selectedindex).apply();
        Log.d("newsdash", "");
    }

    public int getnewsselectedindex(){
        return mSharedPreferences.getInt(PROPERTY_NEWS_INDEX, 0);
    }
```

The following is my fragment class: (i still haven't applied the sharedpreferences to it, am not sure where to add it and how to add it, whether to the position parameter or to the string displayed:

```
public class NewsCategoriesFragment extends AbsLoaderFragment implements OnItemSelectedListener, OnClickListener, OnMenuItemClickedListener,Dialog.OnDismissListener {

    public static final String TAG_NEWS_CATEGORIES_FRAGMENT = "NewsCategoriesFragment";
    private static int mSelectedCategoryCodePosition;

    private NewsCategorySpinnerAdapter mCategoryAdapter;

    private List<AdapterRow> mTopNewsRows;
    private List<AdapterRow> mMyNewsRows;
    private List<AdapterRow> mBreakingViewsRows;
    private List<AdapterRow> mMostReadNewsRows;

    private boolean mHasNonMyNewsCategoriesLoaded;
    private boolean mHasMyNewsCategoriesLoaded;

    private String mSelectedCategory;
    private boolean mFirstTimeLoadingMyNews;
    private boolean mFirstTimeLoadingNonMyNews;
    private MenuHelper mMenuHelper;
    private final ArrayList<String> mMenuItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    private HeaderView headerView;

    private static class MenuItems{
        final static String MANAGE_NEWS_CATEGORIES = Application.getAppResources().getString(R.string.news_menu_manage);
        final static String NEWS_PREFERENCES = Application.getAppResources().getString(R.string.news_menu_preferences);
        static final int MANAGE_NEWS_CATEGORIES_POSITION = 0;
        static final int NEWS_PREFERENCES_POSITION = 1;
    }

    public static NewsCategoriesFragment newInstance(final FragmentManager manager, final int categoryCodePosition) {
        final NewsCategoriesFragment fragment = new NewsCategoriesFragment();
        mSelectedCategoryCodePosition = categoryCodePosition;
        final FragmentInfo fragmentInfo = new FragmentInfo(TransactionMethods.ADD, R.id.header_container);
        fragmentInfo.setFragmentTag(TAG_NEWS_CATEGORIES_FRAGMENT);
        fragmentInfo.doNotAddToBackStack();
        fragmentInfo.setAnimation(R.anim.no_animation, R.anim.no_animation);
        fragmentInfo.setPopAnimation(R.anim.no_animation, R.anim.no_animation);
        FragmentStackManager.getInstance().transitionFragment(manager, fragment, fragmentInfo);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news_categories, container, false);
        headerView = (HeaderView) view.findViewById(R.id.news_categories_container);
        headerView.setContextMenuOnClickListener(this);
        mMyNewsLoader.onCreate(getActivity());

        createMenu();
        return view;
    }

    private void createMenu() {
        mMenuItems.add(MenuItems.MANAGE_NEWS_CATEGORIES);
        mMenuItems.add(MenuItems.NEWS_PREFERENCES);

        mMenuHelper = new MenuHelper(getActivity(), mMenuItems,this,this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(final View view, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        mFirstTimeLoadingNonMyNews = true;
        mFirstTimeLoadingMyNews = true;
        mMyNewsLoader.initLoader();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        mMyNewsLoader.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public Uri onCreateContentUri() {
        final Uri baseUri = NewsContentProvider.USER_CATEGORIES_URI;
        final Builder builder = baseUri.buildUpon().appendQueryParameter(UserCategory.QueryParams.SHORT_LIST, String.valueOf(true));
        return builder.build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCursorLoaded(final Uri uri, final Cursor cursor) {
        Log.d("CategoryIssue", "News - CursorLoaded");
        if (!mFirstTimeLoadingNonMyNews || cursor.getCount() > 0 || !isOperationExecuting()) {
            Log.d("CategoryIssue", "News - CursorLoaded with count " + cursor.getCount());
            PrecacheManager.getInstance().saveNonMyNewsCategoriesForCaching(cursor, mSelectedCategory);

            populateCategoryRows(cursor);

            mHasNonMyNewsCategoriesLoaded = true;
            if (mHasMyNewsCategoriesLoaded) {
                Log.d("CategoryIssue", "News - CursorLoaded showing results");
                showResults(uri);
            }
        }

        if (mFirstTimeLoadingNonMyNews) {
            mFirstTimeLoadingNonMyNews = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onOperationError(Uri uri, RestError error) {
        super.onOperationError(uri, error);
        mHasNonMyNewsCategoriesLoaded = true;
        if (mHasMyNewsCategoriesLoaded) {
            showResults(uri);
        }
    }

    private void updateCategorySpinner() {
        mCategoryAdapter.updateTopNewsRows(mTopNewsRows);
        mCategoryAdapter.updateBreakinViewsRows(mBreakingViewsRows);

        if (mMyNewsRows == null || mMyNewsRows.size() <= 1) {
            mCategoryAdapter.removeMyNews();
        } else {
            mCategoryAdapter.updateMyNewsRows(mMyNewsRows);
        }
    }

    private void initCategorySpinner() {
        mCategoryAdapter = new NewsCategorySpinnerAdapter(getActivity(), mTopNewsRows, mBreakingViewsRows, mMyNewsRows,mMostReadNewsRows);
        headerView.setSpinnerAdapter(mCategoryAdapter);
        headerView.setSpinnerOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        headerView.setSpinnerSelectedItemPosition(mSelectedCategoryCodePosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void showResults(final Uri uri) {
        LayoutUtils.showResults(getView(), headerView.getSpinnerId());
        if (mCategoryAdapter == null) {
            Log.d("CategoryIssue", "init spinner");
            initCategorySpinner();
        } else {
            Log.d("CategoryIssue", "update spinner");
            updateCategorySpinner();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void showNoResults(final Uri uri) {
        LayoutUtils.showNoResult(getView(), headerView.getSpinnerId());
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(final View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.context_menu_button:
                final int actionBarHeight = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.title_main_container).getHeight();
                mMenuHelper.showMenu(getView().getBottom() + actionBarHeight, Gravity.RIGHT);
                BangoHelper.eventSettings();
                if (headerView.isSelected()) {
                    headerView.setSelected(false);
                    Log.i("ImageButtonCheck", "Button is not selected anymore");
                } else {
                    headerView.setSelected(true);
                    Log.i("ImageButtonCheck", "Button is in selected state");
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    private void populateCategoryRows(final Cursor cursor) {
        final Resources resources = getView().getResources();

        mTopNewsRows = new ArrayList<AdapterRow>();
        String categoryTitle = resources.getString(R.string.title_top_news);
        mTopNewsRows.add(new CategoryHeader(categoryTitle));

        mBreakingViewsRows = new ArrayList<AdapterRow>();
        categoryTitle = resources.getString(R.string.title_breakingviews);
        if(SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().isLiteUser()){
        }else{
        mBreakingViewsRows.add(new CategoryHeader(categoryTitle));
        }

        cursor.moveToPosition(-1);

        if(Locale.getDefault().toString().equals("ja_JP")){
            final String categoryName = Application.getAppResources().getString(R.string.news_category_constant_japanese);
            final String categoryCode = "urn:newsml:reuters.com:20090527:SPDOC_1323242720091";
            mTopNewsRows.add(new SpinnerCategoryRow(categoryName, categoryCode, Type.TOP_NEWS));
        } else if(Locale.getDefault().toString().equals("zh_CN")){
            final String categoryName = Application.getAppResources().getString(R.string.news_category_constant_chinese);
            final String categoryCode = "urn:newsml:reuters.com:20100623:SPDOC_1331612320101";
            mTopNewsRows.add(new SpinnerCategoryRow(categoryName, categoryCode, Type.TOP_NEWS));
        }

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            final String navGroup = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(NewsCategory.Columns.NAVIGATION_GROUP));
            final String categoryName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(NewsCategory.Columns.NAME));
            final String categoryCode = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(NewsCategory.Columns.CODE));

            if (NewsCategory.Constants.BREAKINGVIEWS.equals(navGroup)) {
                mBreakingViewsRows.add(new SpinnerCategoryRow(categoryName, categoryCode, Type.BREAKINGVIEWS));
            } else {
                mTopNewsRows.add(new SpinnerCategoryRow(categoryName, categoryCode, Type.TOP_NEWS));
            }
        }
    }

    private final ContentLoader mMyNewsLoader = new ContentLoader() {

        @Override
        public Uri onCreateContentUri() {
            final Builder builder = PreferencesContentProvider.MY_NEWS_CATEGORIES_CONTENT_URI.buildUpon();
            builder.appendQueryParameter(MyNewsCategory.QueryParams.SELECTED_ONLY, String.valueOf(true));
            return builder.build();
        };

        @Override
        public void onOperationError(final Uri uri, final RestError error) {
            super.onOperationError(uri, error);
            mHasMyNewsCategoriesLoaded = true;

            if (mHasNonMyNewsCategoriesLoaded) {
                showResults(uri);
            }
        };

        @Override
        public void onCursorLoaded(final Uri uri, final Cursor cursor) {
            if (!mFirstTimeLoadingMyNews || cursor.getCount() > 0 || !isOperationExecuting()) {
                PrecacheManager.getInstance().saveMyNewsCategoriesForCaching(cursor, mSelectedCategory);
                populateMyNewsCateogryRows(cursor);

                mHasMyNewsCategoriesLoaded = true;
                if (mHasNonMyNewsCategoriesLoaded) {
                    showResults(uri);
                }

                if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
                    if (mCategoryAdapter != null) {
                        mCategoryAdapter.removeMyNews();
                    }
                }
            }

            if (mFirstTimeLoadingMyNews) {
                mFirstTimeLoadingMyNews = false;
            }
        }

        private void populateMyNewsCateogryRows(final Cursor cursor) {
            mMyNewsRows = new ArrayList<AdapterRow>();
            mMyNewsRows.add(new CategoryHeader(getView().getResources().getString(R.string.title_my_news)));
            cursor.moveToPosition(-1);

            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                final String categoryCode = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MyNewsCategory.Columns.FILE_NAME));
                final String categoryName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MyNewsCategory.Columns.NAME));
                mMyNewsRows.add(new SpinnerCategoryRow(categoryName, categoryCode, Type.MY_NEWS));
            }
        };
    };

    @Override
    public void onMenuItemClicked(final int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case MenuItems.MANAGE_NEWS_CATEGORIES_POSITION:
            ManageNewsCategoriesActivity.newInstance(getActivity());
            break;
        case MenuItems.NEWS_PREFERENCES_POSITION:
            NewsPreferencesActivity.newInstance(getActivity());
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        headerView.setSelected(false);
        mMenuHelper.hideMenu();
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(IcsAdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        final SpinnerCategoryRow item = (SpinnerCategoryRow) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

        final NewsFragment parentFragment = (NewsFragment) getParentFragment();

        mSelectedCategory = item.getCategoryCode();

        if (item.getCategoryType() == Type.MY_NEWS) {
            parentFragment.onMyNewsSelected(mSelectedCategory);
            parentFragment.onCategoryPositionSelected(position);
        } else {
            parentFragment.onCategorySelected(mSelectedCategory);
            parentFragment.onCategoryPositionSelected(position);
        }
        parentFragment.dismissPullToRefresh();      
    }
    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        headerView.setSelected(false);
    }
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(IcsAdapterView<?> parent) {
    }
}
```

Also, please let me know if I should add the code for adapter and activity to explain it further, but I figured only fragment should be enough, but I may be wrong

Adding spinneradapter:

```
public class NewsCategorySpinnerAdapter extends CustomRowAdapter<AdapterRow> {

    private List<AdapterRow> mTopNewsRows;
    private List<AdapterRow> mBreakingViewsRows;
    private List<AdapterRow> mMyNewsRows;

    private List<AdapterRow> mRenderList;

    public NewsCategorySpinnerAdapter(final Context context, final List<AdapterRow> topNewsRows, final List<AdapterRow> breakingViewsRows, final List<AdapterRow> myNewsRows) {
        super(context);

        mTopNewsRows = topNewsRows;
        mBreakingViewsRows = breakingViewsRows;
        mMyNewsRows = myNewsRows;

        mRenderList = new ArrayList<AdapterRow>();
        mRenderList.addAll(topNewsRows);
        mRenderList.addAll(breakingViewsRows);
        //mRenderList.addAll(myNewsRows);

        if (myNewsRows != null && myNewsRows.size() > 0) {
            mRenderList.addAll(myNewsRows);
        }

        if (mostReadNewsRows != null && mostReadNewsRows.size() > 0) {
            mRenderList.addAll(mostReadNewsRows);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void setEntries(final List<AdapterRow> renderList) {
        mRenderList = renderList;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<AdapterRow> getEntries() {
        return mRenderList;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        return getEntries().get(position).getDropDownView(mContext, convertView);
    }

    public void updateTopNewsRows(final List<AdapterRow> topNewsRows) {
        if (mTopNewsRows != null) {
            mTopNewsRows = topNewsRows;
            recontructRenderList();
        } else {
            getEntries().addAll(topNewsRows);
        }

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void updateBreakinViewsRows(final List<AdapterRow> breakingViewsRows) {
        if (mBreakingViewsRows != null) {
            mBreakingViewsRows = breakingViewsRows;
            recontructRenderList();
        } else {
            getEntries().addAll(breakingViewsRows);
        }

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void updateMyNewsRows(final List<AdapterRow> myNewsRows) {
        if (mMyNewsRows != null) {
            mMyNewsRows = myNewsRows;
            recontructRenderList();
        } else {
            getEntries().addAll(myNewsRows);
        }

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }




    private void recontructRenderList() {
        getEntries().clear();

        addSection(mTopNewsRows);
        addSection(mBreakingViewsRows);
        addSection(mMyNewsRows);
    }

    private void addSection(final List<AdapterRow> section) {
        if (section != null && !section.isEmpty()) {
            getEntries().addAll(section);
        }
    }

    public void removeMyNews() {
        if (ArrayUtils.isNotEmpty(mMyNewsRows)) {
            mRenderList.removeAll(mMyNewsRows);
            mMyNewsRows = null;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }


    }

}
```

Comment: Why not saving the value instead of the position?

Comment: How do I do that? can you explain with respect to my code?

Answer (score 3):

Use this code in the onItemSelected() method and save the selected value's position of your spinner :

```
int Choice = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("FileName",0);
SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = sharedPref.edit();
prefEditor.putInt("spinnerChoice",Choice);
prefEditor.commit();
```

To set the choice from sharedPreferences :

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("FileName",MODE_PRIVATE);
int spinnerValue = sharedPref.getInt("spinnerChoice",-1);
if(spinnerValue != -1) 
spinner.setSelection(spinnerValue);
```

Comment: i dont think you need to save position. instead you can save the selected text. so if you delete or add then still you will be able to get the correct item wrt its text. but if you save position then forexample you delete items before selected item then that position will be get false/wrong, but if you save the selected item's text then you  will get correct item. Hope you'll get my poing.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get the selected string:

```
String text = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

And this to set the spinner again after an item is deleted or so:

```
ArrayAdapter myAdap = (ArrayAdapter) spinner.getAdapter();
int spinnerPosition = myAdap.getPosition(text);
spinner.setSelection(spinnerPosition);
```

Comment: shouldn't I use sharedprefs so it remembers my selection?

Comment: That doesn't solve this problem: "Now,everytime I select an item in the spinner say "germany" and then I click on the menu button and add or remove any item above or below germany, the position shifts on the spinner too , to the previously selected item or to the next item."

Comment: the thing is item is not deleted, it just moves one step back or forth in the spinner based on the selection made. I tried this code: mCategoryAdapter.getItem(mSelectedcategory) considering i set mSelectedcategory AS item.getCategoryName().toString(); I might be doing it compeltely wrong, can you check the function onItemSelected and updateCategorySpinner called in showResults, where the update is happening and eventually affecting the spinner, and explain w.r.t it? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can save selected item text on sharedpreference(you know how,so I don't say it again). then afte you click on add button and add new String to your array call this:

```
spinner.setSelection(yourArrayList.indexOf("yourPreviusNameThatRetriveFromSharedPreference"));
```

Comment: What is this spinner? With respect to my code, is it item which is defined as a spinnercategoryrow? Can you explain with respect to my code?

Comment: where you define your spinner?(I not find it in your code)

Comment: please check the adapter code, where i define the spinner adapter rows

Answer (score 0):

You can save your last selected position in SharedPreference and when user click on spinner than set spinner.setSelection(position). which is saved in your SharedPreference. This is the only one solution for solving this problem.

Comment: can you explain with respect to my code. I tried to do that but it didnt change anything, where do I call the get method and where do i save the position

Comment: What I´d do is to save the itemId instead of the index and whenever you restore the screen, run through the list geting items and comparing the id, if equals, select that index.

Comment: can u explain with respect to my code as a separate answer, it'll be helpful.I tried everything but it doesnt work